# SEO friendly URL's with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

Can anybody please help me with some URL rewriting?

I have (for example) these pages:

```
www.mydomain.com/test/gallery.asp?id=2
www.mydomain.com/test/gallery.asp?id=3
```

and want them to be requested as:

```
www.mydomain.com/photos/people
www.mydomain.com/photos/wildlife
```

I'm using IIS and at first my hosting provider was using ISAPI_Rewrite with a httpd.ini file, now they have switched to Helicon Ape with a .htaccess file.
See: http://www.isapirewrite.com/ and http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

I tried it the ISAPI_Rewrite way:

```
RewriteRule /photos/people /test/gallery.asp?id=2 [I,L]
RewriteRule /photos/wildlife /test/gallery.asp?id=3 [I,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have anything in you httpd.parse.errors file?

Comment: I don't see a parse errors file. I'm using Helicon Ape with mod_rewrite and IIS, no Apache. Where should the parse errors file do appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^photos/(.*)$ test/gallery.asp?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

first row is test if it isn't file

second row is test if it isn't directory

third will redirect photos/wildlife?a=true to test/gallery.asp?id=wildlife&a=true

if you don't want to redirect with a=true, just give out QSA ;)

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work for me. I tried other examples of the documentation also. No results. Can I check if the rewrite functionality is properly working?

Comment: It's working now. The provider accidentally turned it off ... $@!*X#!@#