# .htaccess syntax error when shorting URL's

Tags: .htaccess

I've read a few posts and tutorials on this so far but still not getting the full picture.

I want to shorten my URLs from **?action=viewArticle&articleId=7** to whatever the title is(held in title table on MySQL)

I understand that to do this you replace the messy part with **$1**, true? and that you also use **$** after the character set to signify the start of where you want the server to change.

I just uploaded this code below as .htaccess and then immediately it returned a full page 500 error. I deleted the file. What am I writing wrong?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ ?action=$1&articleId=$2
```

I put **$2** at the end becuase it seemed like the logical progression. I would like to avoid uploading it incorrectly again.

Comment: Please provide a real example of `from url` and desired `to url` so I could help you more accurately

Comment: Ok so the real example is like in the post and desired would be the name of the article only. ?action=viewArticle&articleId=7 -> /blog-number

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEO friendly URL's with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547806/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$1` `$2` represent back references. Those are created by parentheses `()` Your rule has got only one opening and closing bracket, thus creating only one back reference.

You are getting an error because `$2` doesn't exist.